# Replying to an email with a + extension

Tags: email, gmail, spam-prevention, google-workspace, auto-reply

I sign up for accounts using “myemail+customextension@host.ext” and this is all fine and good. I just want to know how to reply to emails using that custom extension rather than “myemail@host.ext”

Comment: I don't do gmail so I'm not sure if you can add extra identities or customize the from address when sending, but Thunderbird allows this, and Roundcube webmail allows this as well.   Also, you should be aware that many "validation" regexes are "broken" and won't allow the `+` character - I changed the extension on my servers to be a minus sign/dash `-` and have had no issues using it.

Comment: So you recommend the ‘-‘ character over ‘+’ because of sanitization?

Comment: Exactly.  Incorrect regexes, etc.  Of course, server side functions like PHP's `filter_var` and such handle it fine, it is the self-written validation that a lot of forms use in Javascript before submitting.

Comment: If using Gmail, it does not allow for sending of email from + extension addresses, _(at least that I'm aware of)_.  The + extension is there to allow alias creation for sending email to, but since the from address must always be the account's email, there is no way that I'm aware of to get around that.  I've tried doing so via `sendmail`, `ssmtp`, and `postfix` and I've never been able to do so on any of my servers.

Comment: That stinks. What about alternative clients like ProtonMail or ZohoMail?

Comment: @pecuk Microsoft allows for sending from aliases with Outlook.com email accounts.  The only downside is you're limited to ~10 aliases... you can delete and re-create aliases, but you can only have a max of 10 at any given time.

Comment: How does iCloud handle something like this?

Comment: Are you asking how to configure the Gmail web interface to put that in your `From:` header? Basically, you have to configure each as a separate personality IIRC. Using a real email client instead may be the easiest workaround.

Comment: @tripleee what are some good email clients with minimal telemetry and bs? Microsoft products aren’t too hot for me :p

Comment: It's probably too old-school for you, but Gnus certainly fulfills your requirements. I guess you could make Thunderbird almost palatable (but not RFC-compliant) with a sprinkling of plugins, but my personal solution was to not use Gmail in the first place. I'm vaguely used to the quirks of Fastmail's web interface, which supports this use case nicely, but of course then you'd switch providers too.

Comment: ProtonMail + Thunderbird seems like a good mixture... Hm.